# highcharts: How do I change the color of the chart above?

Tags: highcharts

For example I want to turn red.

How can i do this?

[image]

**Update:**

I use highchart library.

This is my code And I want to take up all the space. That is, red, stick to the top:

I use this code but i do not answer.

I was very searching and very test it.

What do i do?

Help me, please!

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/6tg4rnjp/

```
{
    yAxis: [{
        visible: false,
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        height: '50%',
        lineWidth: 2,
    }, {
        visible: false,
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        top: '50%',
        height: '50%',
        offset: 0,
        lineWidth: 2
    }],
    series: [{
        type: 'line',
        showInLegend: false,
        color: '#00B1FC',
        data: [50, 15, 8, 25, 84, 74, 26, 54, 29, 35, 9, 15, 17, 18, 54, 26, 34, 27, 26, 18, 57, 24, 35, 16, 24, 25, 27],
        marker: {
            enabled: false,
            states: {
                hover: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                inactive: {
                    opacity: 1
                }
            }
        },
        states: { hover: 'none' },
        fillColor: '#F7F8FA'
    }, {
        type: 'polygon',
        enableMouseTracking: false,
        showInLegend: false,
        color: 'red',
        data: [
            [16, 10],
            [0, 10],
            [0, 1],
            [8, 9],
            [10, 3],
            [11, 2],
            [13, 6],
            [14, 3],
            [15, 1],
            [16, 1]
        ],
        states: {
            inactive: {
                opacity: 1
            }
        },
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        color: '#94E3FD',
        pointWidth: 1,
        showInLegend: false,
        marker: {
            enabled: true,
            states: {
                hover: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                inactive: {
                    opacity: 1
                }
            }
        },
        data: [50, 15, 8, 25, 84, 74, 26, 54, 29, 35, 9, 15, 17, 18, 54, 26, 34, 27, 26, 18, 57, 24, 35, 16, 24, 25, 27],
        yAxis: 1,
        states: { hover: 'none' }
    }],
    chart: {
        backgroundColor: '#F4F7FA',
        margin: [0, -5, 0, -5]
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        visible: false
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: true
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    navigation: {
        buttonOptions: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, the best solution for this case will be via using the **polygon** series.

Code:

```
{
    type: 'polygon',
    enableMouseTracking: false,
    showInLegend: false,
    color: 'red',
    data: [
      [16, 10],
      [0, 10],
      [0, 1],
      [8, 9],
      [10, 3],
      [11, 2],
      [13, 6],
      [14, 3],
      [15, 1],
      [16, 1]
    ],
    states: {
      inactive: {
        opacity: 1
      }
    },
  }
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pg6u4dns/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.polygon

IMPORTANT - remember to include the highcharts-more module in your HTML document.

Comment: What is the method of obtaining data numbers?

Comment: I realized that this option needs to put the data manually which is not so good, so I think that a better solution will be using the area series type with set threshold. See: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5e69uvhy/